# Authenticating user by ID recorded in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following problem: I have Events Model, which contains data about event and organisator (user who created it - users ID). I want to make possibility to Edit/Remove this event only by creator. I don't know how to compare user ID from database with ID of real user, who wants to make action.

Should I add authorization in Edit/Delete methods in Events Model Controler or is there a different way to check this ID?

EventsModelController:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string placeString, string nameString, DateTime data, DateTime time)
        {
            if(HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ViewBag.userID = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            var events = from e in _context.EventsModel
                         select e;
            return View(await events.ToListAsync());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("id,event_type,date,place,name,hour,tickets,tickets_per_person,organisator")] EventsModel eventsModel)
        {
            var userID = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            eventsModel.organisator = userID;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(eventsModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(eventsModel);
        }
```

I'm using ViewBag to show options to Delete/Remove (view Index):

```
             <td>
                @if (ViewBag.userID == item.organisator)
                 {
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.id">Edit</a> 
                 }
                | <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.id">Details</a> |
                @if (ViewBag.userID == item.organisator)
                 {
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.id">Delete</a>
                 }
            </td>
```

For now, only creator can see options Edit and Delete in list of events, but everyone have access to this methods.

**UPDATE**

My final solution:
I added method called "getUser" in EventsModel. When user wants to call Edit or Delete method - I'm checking current user ID with the one written in object.

Fragment of EventsModelsController:

```
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var eventsModel = await _context.EventsModel.FindAsync(id);
            if (eventsModel.getUser() != HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString())
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            if (eventsModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(eventsModel);
        }
```

Comment: Why cant you just check the "organisator" id ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm checking it but i want to full disable access to this methods. If i'm checking creator ID i have access to this methods - I can see Edit window, but changes won't be saved.

Comment: Yeah, i meant in the controller. You can even make it a middle ware, though i wouldn't recommend that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is, there are many ways to do this. This depends on what you want your view to look like, but if you simply want to restrict the route you can create a role for that authentication, such as

```
[Authorize(Roles = "organisator")]
```

Middleware, can be used here as well. You should be able to just use the authenication middle ware by adding policy to be used and a handler to check the context to see if the user is the organizer of said event. But, if you project does not allow this, a custom one can achieve the same effect.

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("PolicyOrganisator", policy =>...);
        });
```

...Hanlder

```
if (context.User.userID == context.Request... ) 
{
    context.Succeed();
}
```

You can also just check in the controller, as you mention in your questions. Append extra data in your model to flag if this user can or cannot get.

```
calss EventsModel {
 ...
 bool canEdit { get => userID == item.organisator; } 
}
```

If this is the only route you are trying to restrict, then i don't see what is wrong with adding an if statement at the top of the method to check if you should redirect. I added links on the bottom of the page, because the examples will change dependence on how you setup your project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes

Comment: Yeah, but if i have x users, roles makes sence? Because for example User1 created Event1 and Event3, User2 created Event2. If both have role organisator, both can edit all events?

Comment: I see your point, in that case you can even make a custom attribute and pass in the ID's

Comment: Awesome, you can pm me any other questions you have, before you make another post. Please mark my post as the answer, and submit your a snippet of the final solution.